# Install Ruby using rbenv in a bash script

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, installer

I want to write an automated bash script for installing Ruby and Rails using rbenv, but I am getting session reload issues in the terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Installing rbenv.."
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
reset
echo "Finished installing rbenv"

#!/bin/bash
rbenv -v
echo "Installing ruby.."
sudo rbenv install 2.2.3
rbenv global 2.2.3
echo "Finished installing ruby"
ruby -v

echo "gem: --no-document" > ~/.gemrc

echo "Installing rails.."
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo gem install bundler
gem install rails -v 4.2.3
rbenv rehash
echo "Finished installing rails"
rails -v
rbenv rehash
```

Comment: What do you mean by this: *"But I am getting issue of session reload in terminal."*

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot can be improved on a simple installer script like this.
I have a few tips but nothing really significant.

The script doesn't check if it has already been executed.
If you run it again by mistake, it will append to `~/.bashrc` lines that were already there.

As a simple workaround, you could add `-e` flag to the shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
```

This will cause the script to exit on the first error.
Which will happen on the first `git clone` command,
which will fail because the local clone already exists.
The script will stop there and not reach the lines that append again to `.bashrc`.

Speaking of shebang, you have a second `#!/bin/bash` in the middle of the script, which was probably a copy-paste mistake and has no purpose there, so should be removed.